# Getting char from array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I have an array of strings and an array of ints. Usually when I want to get a certain char from string I use:

```
string[char_position];
```

But when I have two arrays the same way of getting char doesn't work:

```
string[i][char_position[i]];
```

How can I get certain char from array of strings?

Comment: A bit more explanation of errors observed will be useful.

Comment: string is an array of strings and char_position is array of ints.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this instead:

```
string[i][char_position];
```

You sholdn't be subscripting char_position.

Comment: OP mentions an array of ints, which suggests `char_position` could indeed need subscripting.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that's true, but he suggests that string[char_position] indeed works.

Answer (score 0):

In first example you are using `char_position` as `int` but in second you are using it as `array`. Either one of this is wrong obviously if you mean same variable in two cases. But what it looks like you want to access `j`th charecter of `i`th string. If it is that then

```
string[i][j]; // j is position of char in string[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

`string[i][char_position[i]];` means the instructions:

- get the **INTEGER** from `char_position` **array** indexed at i
- get the character in `i`th string, in the **position** got from the first step

This is valid and correct ONLY if char_position is an ARRAY and not a SCALAR VARIABLE.

On the other hand, if char_position IS a scalar variable THEN:

string[i][char_position] is the way to retrieve `char_position`th character in the `i`th string, in the array of character arrays `string`